# Method parameter auto completion for a class instance

Tags: python, class, methods, autocomplete

I am trying to get auto completion of method parameter names for class instances but can't quite figure it out. Take this example class:

```
class Abc:
    def meth(param):
        pass
```

If I type `Abc.meth(p` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> I see the expected completion of `param=`:

[image]

However, if I try to do the same with an instance of the class `Abc().meth(p`, I don't see `param` in the completion results:

[image]

I see the same behavior in both JupyterLab and VS Code, and the fact that this works for instances of other packages such as scikit learn, I think there is something I am missing.

[image]

How can I get method parameter completion for an instance of my `Abc()` class similar to the `LinearRegression` class above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on experimentation on JupyterLab Version 3.2.9, this seems to be because the autocomplete tries to account for implicit parameters like `self` and `cls`. Including a `self` parameter should mostly fix your issues.

```py
class Abc:
    def meth(arg1, arg2, arg3):
        pass
```

These are the completion options I was presented for the class above:

| Decorator | Abc.meth | Abc().meth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| None | arg1, arg2, arg3 | arg2, arg3 |
| @staticmethod | arg1, arg2, arg3 | arg2, arg3 |
| @classmethod | arg2, arg3 | arg3 |

The standard behavior is fine, but the results for `Abc().meth` are wrong with both decorators. As mentioned in the docs for [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) and [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

> method can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance (such as C().f())

So both columns should have been the same when decorators are used, but it always omits one parameter from `Abc().meth`, presumably for `self`. And even though `cls` is correctly handled for `Abc.meth` when using `@classmethod`, it ends up omitting two parameters in `Abc().meth` instead.

---

Testing with Visual Studio Code 1.67.1 gave the correct autocomplete options for all cases. So the missing suggestion you experienced there is expected behavior since `param` takes the place of `self` and there are no other parameters.